# Do bread bins really keep homemade breads fresh?

Tags: bread, storage-method

I usually keep my homemade breads for a day or two in a ziplock bag. I recently felt like buying a good-looking bread box/tin to not use plastic bags that often (I keep the bags for as long as possible unless used for something like cinnamon rolls) and a bread box looks good on the breakfast table. I was reading some reviews that people complained about their bread going moldy in the box although it was a pretty fancy/expensive one. Since I wouldn't spend money on something useless which takes some space in my small kitchen, I'd like to make sure it is a good buy.

I also read [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91866/why-does-storing-bread-in-a-plastic-grocery-bag-keep-it-fresh-longer) on plastic bags keeping the bread fresh for a few days and ask myself whether I should keep using ziplock bags.

Also, there different types of them,
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bread bins are very useful in houses with mice. Most are designed in such a way mice can not get in. I would still package my bread before putting it in.

Comment: I wonder how the box that suggests similar questions based on the title and the body of the question I am going to ask never show me the ones that my question with be linked to and closed as duplicate of them. something does not function properly.

Comment: @Gigili the questions in the box are found by the system, based on similarities with your question title and body. When I close a question as a duplicate, I manually search for older questions I remember we have on the site, and after finding them, I close, manually adding them as duplicates. You are correct that it would be better for everybody if they had been found during you posting the question, but the system is not that good yet. Maybe if you do a manual search before posting, you will sometimes find the older questions, depending on your search term choice.

Comment: @rumtscho: Noted, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid anything that can't have a good wash.  I've had wooden bread bins in the past and crumbs in crevices can go mouldy and spread the mould to bread until you give up and throw the bread bin away

These days I either use the enamelled cast iron pot I bake in (and which therefore fits my boules perfectly) or a plastic box that originally held a lot of biscuits (if I bake in a loaf tin or use the bread machine).  Both can go through the dishwasher; the cast iron additionally gets sterilised at 240°C before baking.  The plastic box is presumably more airtight, but both keep home made bread fine for a few days, which is as long as I need.  It's important to make sure the bread is completely cool before putting it in, to avoid condensation, but not to leave it too long.

Comment: Excellent point, easy to wash and clean. Noted.

Answer (score 2):

They stop it drying out quite so fast, not much else as far as I can tell.
There may be some small benefit from the interior being dark, but not really one I could categorically state would be helpful.

I would never re-use plastic bags for bread, though, unless you wash & dry between uses, otherwise any beginnings of mould will just proliferate & spread to whatever you next put in the bag.

It's always a balance, though - crusty bread will go tough before it goes off, things like baguette will either dry to a rock, or become really chewy, depending on if you let them breathe slightly or not.
Supermarket baguette tends to be supplied in a perforated bag. Left out, it's a truncheon, in a ziplok it's tough as boot-leather… but in the perforated bag in a bread bin, it just about survives.

Comment: "crusty bread will go tough before it goes off", I'd love to have a kitchen sign with that line!